# Issue with Bifurcation Plot for Driven Pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, computational-physics, chaos-theory, bifurcation

I'm trying to create a bifurcation plot for a driven damped pendulum. In particular, I'm trying to recreate the plot found in Taylor's 'Classical Mechanics' (page 484) for a driving strength $\gamma$ in the range $1.060 \leq \gamma \leq 1.087$:

[image]

I believe I have the code down and I can reproduce the main properties of the plot, however for $\gamma \geq 1.081$ the points shift down a couple of units which causes a large discontinuity. I'd appreciate any help on the matter. I've attached an image of my result below.

[image: Bifurcation plot with discontinuity.]

Comment: I guess you mean the discontinuity around 1.081?

Comment: Yes, apologies for that. I've looked at the points at that $\gamma$ and compared it to values for the previous value $\gamma-0.001$ and the results do not align. I've ran the algorithm a couple times and each time the same gap appears. Looks unlikely to be a visual bug.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141653/

Comment: And this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96004/

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin, Your comments seemed to have answered the question, perhaps you could consider including the main information and posting as an answer?

Comment: It might be better to include the equation you're using and perhaps some pseudocode to outline what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details it's hard to answer precisely, but two possibilities are:

- As the maximum amplitude increases, some numerical angle normalization makes a jump with no meaning (e.g., from $2\pi$ to $4\pi$) - that might very well be the case here, if "End Position" in your plot is normalized by $2\pi$.
- This system exhibits multistability (i.e., it can have more than one stable final state, for a given set of parameter values) and which state is reached depends on which [basin of attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Basins_of_attraction) the initial condition belongs to. As $\gamma$ is varied, the boundary between different basins moves in phase space, and the fixed initial condition being used to construct the bifurcation diagram might suddenly find itself on a different basin at a certain $\gamma^*$: in this way, the diagram shows the bifurcations of attractor $A$ for $\gamma<\gamma^*$, and of attractor $B$ afterwards.

Perhaps supporting this second possibility are the following diagrams found in the web:

- Kinchin & Mullens' [Damped Driven Pendulum Project](https://stephenmullens.co.uk/static/home/docs/Damped_Driven_Pendulum.pdf):

[image]

- Gasenzer's [The chaotic physical pendulum](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~gasenzer/index.php?n1=teaching&n2=chaos):
  [image]
- LeBailly's [Master thesis](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/64k5r379):

[image]

- Rinberg's [Chaos Pendulum Lab report](http://216.92.172.113/courses/phys39/phys39%20reports%20S2010/Rinberg_ChaosLab2.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was also having a problem generating a bifurcation diagram for this system, with small pieces and even an entire branch missing. Mysteriously, my Poincare sections were just not catching everything. While it looks like you were having a mod pi issue, it turns out there are also 3 distinct attractors, so 3 different basins of attraction: stafusa was correct on both counts, this system exhibits multi-stability. In fact, the basins of attraction turn out to have the Wada property: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-28119-0

After testing out enough initial conditions, I managed to generate a fairly complete diagram. (I think the basins are changing shape, though, so it's still missing a few tiny bits.) Gasenzer's plot appears to be the most accurate. Here's a larger version of Gasenzer's, as well as the plot of theta v.s. A:

[image]

[image]

If you are or anyone else is interested in the Matlab code, feel free to contact me. It also works for things like Duffing, Rossler, etc.